# Can't Click Element In Selenium Because 'Object Obscures It'

Tags: django, selenium

This selenium functional test was working a week ago. Since then I have made a lot of changes to this page and now the test is failing with

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element <input id="id_test_date" class="checkboxinput custom-control-input" name="test_date" type="checkbox"> is not clickable at point (8,470) because another element <label class="custom-control-label"> obscures it
```

I have tried waiting for the element to load, but it doesn't help. This is the html

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div id="div_id_test_date" class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="test_date" class="checkboxinput custom-control-input" id="id_test_date">
        <label for="id_test_date" class="custom-control-label">
            Do you know what month you will take the test?
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't know of the `::before::` is causing the issue, if it is I don't know why as it didn't used to be an issue and I don't know how to fix it.

I think this is unrelated, but I get the following error msg in console

```
Uncaught TypeError: option required is not recognized!
    at Boolean.<anonymous> (bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js:1)
```

I have searched a lot and can't find a solution, many people seem to fix this issue by waiting for the element to load. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What xpaths you have used so far?

Comment: I havent used any as the exact ```get_element_by_name``` that im using now worked fine a week ago and I havent actually changed this checkbox at all. Should I experiment with xpaths? (I've also never used them so they didn't really occur to me)

Comment: Go for xpath and add some expected condition of selenium before operating on the element. It should work in this case.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked. I didn't have high hopes as I thought ```xpath``` would essentially be the same as ```get_element_by_name```. I didn't even have to add expected conditions. Thank you